# Execution time between PhoneGap and Android application

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I wrote two mobile applications to test execution time in two methods. 
Both applications consist of only a button which calls a matrix multiplication method:

Java method:

```
public void matrismult(int[][] a, int[][] b)
{
    int n = a.length;
    int[][] C = new int[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                C[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In the java method I use System.currentTimeMillis(); to measure the execution time and in JavaScript I use performance.now();

JavaScript method:

```
function myFunction(m1,m2) {

    for (var i = 0; i < m1.length; i++) {
        result[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < m2[0].length; j++) {
            var sum = 0;
            for (var k = 0; k < m1[0].length; k++) {
                sum += m1[i][k] * m2[k][j];
            }
            result[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
}
```

The execution time for the Java method when I run the matrix multiplication 10k times on a 10x10 matrix is 6500 Miliseconds. When I do the same on the PhoneGap application I get the execution time 139 Miliseconds.

I'm kinda sure I'm doing something terribly wrong since it feels like the android application shouldn't be that slow. But I don't really know what, could someone point me in the right direction?

edit: the matrices are the same

edit2: How I measure the execution time

```
            long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            dostuff();
            long endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long exec = endtime - starttime;
```

Comment: I think you should use the Debug class to claculate time of execution, how are you sure of time when you use `System.currentTimeMillis();` in a multithreaded platform?

Comment: I didn't really think of that. I'm gonna use the Debug class and see if there are any big changes.

Comment: how do you measure the time?

Comment: -- On a side note, Java is the Red Pill, Java is truth.

Comment: Added how I measure the execution time, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You are doing it wrong, for first I'd suggest using Nano Time. Second, you should go for an iterative approach if you still stick to this way. [This can be helpful](http://hoccer.com/2010/09/measuring-performance-with-android/)

Comment: Gonna check it out, thanks friend.